# Unable to give input in Vs Code

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code

I installed VS code in my laptop and every code is running well in every language but the programs which needs input are not taking input , I uninstalled the VS Code and again installed it but the problem is still same...any solution please

Comment: Try running your programs from the terminal.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your antivirus

Comment: @drescherjm I think he is running code from the Output window, and not from the terminal window

Comment: Which comands do you use to run the code? Do you have any extensions installed? Are you using Visual C++ build tools or g++?

Comment: I expect that if the OP does not respond to the questions that we will not be able to solve the question. At best we can make guesses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

Follow below steps.
1. Press *ctr+,* to go to settings.
2. Search  **Code-runner:Run in terminal**
3. check Code-runner:Run in terminal.
Now You are able to give inputs. Thanks.

Comment: It is worth noting that [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) is an extension which needs to be installed first. Once that's done, the steps above can be followed.