# Issue in python code input function isn't working properly

Tags: python, input

I am facing a problem when I write the code of python in vs-code. I write the same as showing in video code with harry. But I don't understand how to solve it. Just stop working never do any other task. Here is the code.

**input**

```
a = input("what is your name: ")
print("My name is zeeshan", a)
```

**Output**

```
what is your name:
```

Comment: What are you entering for the input?  What sequence of keys are you using to do that?

Comment: I write my name for entering input. I just write this simple code. I'm new in python. and not sure about sequence of keys.

Comment: Did you press enter after typing it? Maybe it is a misconfiguration of vscode

Comment: Did you type it in console or in the code?

Comment: You know what you typed, but you don't know what keys you used to type it?

Comment: Yes, I press enter after typing it. how to configure VS. It is working properly when I print any command but in input function it is not working.

Comment: I type it in Vs code.

Comment: Ok, I got you, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964835/unable-to-give-input-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to give input in Vs Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964835/unable-to-give-input-in-vs-code)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Caridorc. It's working in terminal .

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  Especially Caridorc.

Answer (score 0):

after you run this code you need to type to the console your desired output:

after you see the output

```
what is your name:
```

type the name and press enter (then the rest of your code will run)